# Does Spring really gives new transaction for each thread?

Tags: spring

I am working on a project which makes extensive use of spring transactions. I t so happened that i was throwing an exception AND NOT HANDLING IT PROPERLY which does not commit or rollback the transact Ion. So the connection remains active even when the thread is stopped. When new request to the web server ( Apache tomcat 7.0) comes the spring provides the earlier connection to the new thread.  Since the thread didn't started the connection so the thread couldn't close it either ie .commit doesn't work. because of which the objects are not getting persisted in database in the consequent transactions even when there is no exception. How can i work around the problem so that i can detect where is the actual problem happening or can a design an exit point where i can explicitly close the transaction before response is sent to browser.

Comment: Your diagnostic is probably wrong. Spring commits or rollbacks the transaction for you, whatever the way you handle the exception: if a runtime exception is thrown from a transactional method, the transaction is rollbacked. Otherwise, it's committed. It's your responsibility, however, to always close JDBC connections, in a finally block. If you use Spring's JdbcTemplate, Spring also does that for you.

Comment: Perhaps u have never used the Programatic Transaction Approah of Spring. If you have a look at the Spring code for the same, we can see that the transaction is thread based, where TransactionStatus object is bound to every function with isOwner as boolean flag which gives the function the power of final commit decision.

Comment: If we don't write any .Commit or .rollback in owner function then the object reference for TransactionStatus is lost , when the same thread is returned from thread pool the new transaction never starts and it get wrapped in the earlier transaction , eventually u can never commit the transction and we end up closed connections after some time of inactivity.

Comment: The same things are handled by SPring in annotation approach as it is based on concept of AOP where the transaction misses is not possible.

Comment: Refer to the bug: [link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13789)

Answer (score 0):

A runtime unchecked exception or error that is thrown from a `@Transactional` method will rollback that transaction by default; a return or a checked exception will commit the transaction by default. You can tell Spring to override that behaviour using the annotation type elements of the `@Transactional` annotation.

The Spring Framework reference manual has an [entire chapter devoted to transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction). You need to read and understand that as your starting point.

Comment: A *runtime* exception rollbacks the transaction. Checked exceptions don't.

Comment: Clarified the answer.